# Is code in Framework/Zend considered plugins?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Once you download the zend framework, you get a list of folders in `Framework-1.10.8/Zend`

```
Acl 
Amf
Application
Auth
Barcode
...
```

Are these considered plugins, or are they modules, or are they just assisting libraries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are the components which make up the Zend Framework.

Comment: So they're neither modules nor plugins. I'm a bit confused what zend means by modules and plugins. In zend, the 2 don't seem to be the same, but in the outside world plugins = modules.

Comment: Modules in ZF-lingo generally refer to things such as a "shopping cart module" or "guestbook module" - in other words, they are a group of controllers, views and related helpers or models which make up a certain functionality. Plugins usually refer to front controller plugins (also called just controller plugins), which are used to execute code in specific phases of the request cycle.